# Azure Authentication on Web App and calls to Intranet Windows Authentication Web Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We have a .Net Web API deployed on Azure and we are in process of configuring it to use Azure AD Authentication. We need that Web API to make calls to an on premise SOAP web service which uses windows authentication, for which we are setting up hybrid vpn connection with Azure. Is it possible to configure web apps and azure to achieve this? And if yes, how?

Comment: Windows authentication... kerberos? Then no, you can't do kerberos without domain joined machines and your App Service PaaS VM instance(s) can't be domain joined. Your on-prem app needs to be able to consume JWT or SAML - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims

Comment: MAYBE you could throw ADFS at it, although not sure if that would work either, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/whereismysolution/2017/07/25/using-a-jwt-on-a-windows-service/